# Maven assembly - Error reading assemblies

Tags: plugins, maven-2, assemblies, maven-descriptor

I have defined a personalized jar-with-dependencies assembly descriptor. However, when I execute it with mvn assembly:assembly, I get :

```
...
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] javax/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] [assembly:assembly {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.
```

My **jar-with-dependencies.xml** is in **src/main/resources/assemblies/**.

My assembly descriptor is the following :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<assembly>
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <unpackOptions>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/LICENSE*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/README*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </unpackOptions>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF/services</directory>
            <outputDirectory>META-INF/services</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

</assembly>
```

And my project pom.xml is :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.my.app.HowTo</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When mvn assembly:assembly is performed, dependencies are unpacked and I get the previous error when unpack has finished.

Moreover, if I execute mvn -e assembly:assembly it is say that no descriptors has been found, however it try to unpack dependencies and a JAR with dependencies is created but it doesn't contain META-INF/services/* as specified in descriptor :

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.AssemblyReadException: No assembly descriptors found.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.DefaultAssemblyReader.readAssemblies(DefaultAssemblyReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:352)
    ... 19 more
```

I don't see my error. Does someone has a solution ?

Comment: Check this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/sharing-descriptors.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, when using your own descriptor, you must specify **the path to** your customized descriptor file (by the way, you can use any location but putting the descriptor in  `src/main/resources` is maybe not the best choice, you don't really want the descriptor to be packaged in your application, I'd use the standard location which is `src/main/assembly` as mentioned in [this page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)).

```
<descriptors>
  <descriptor>src/main/assembly/jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
</descriptors>
```

Second, your `configuration` element is currently inside an `execution` block and is thus specific to **this** execution. In other words, it won't apply if you run `assembly:assembly`  on the command line. So, if you want to call `assembly:assembly` with a custom descriptor, either use:

```
mvn assembly:assembly -Ddescriptor=path/to/descriptor.xml
```

Or move the `configuration` outside the `execution` element (to make the configuration global):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>path/to/descriptor.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
     ...
   </build>
   ...
</project>
```

Comment: I have edited path and moved jar-with-dependencies.xml in src/main/assembly/ like you mention but I get always the same error. It is very amazing.

Comment: I am not sure it is a path error. If I indicate a wrong path, execution is stopped before to unpack dependencies by the following message : 

  Error locating assembly descriptor file ... (No such file or directory)

Whereas in my case with correct path, I get :

  Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.

Comment: I have the same problem. The assembly plugin seems to be buggy, or very user unfriendly.

Comment: Weird.  It actually works when "mvn package" is run,  but I get the same failure as everybody when doing "mvn assembly:single"

Comment: Actually, the standard location mentionned in the page you are pointing is : src/assembly  ("Assembly descriptors"), not src/main/assembly. I guess it's because u can package for dev/test environments as well. Probably not related to the encoutered errors though.

Comment: Put descriptor file in `src/main/resources/assemblies` is the only way to share it among multiple projects, refer: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/sharing-descriptors.html

Answer (score 4):

assembly is trying to open /assemblies/${ref}.xml in classpath 
check this

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/assembly/io/DefaultAssemblyReader.html