# What this error means? "maven build failure: src\assembly\zip.xml does not exist

Tags: java, maven

I have inherited `java` `maven` project. This is compiled and run at `java 1.8`. When I ran `maven` `clean install -U` command I got build failure message. I tried to search for a clue but I haven't been able to find it yet.

I don't believe this `zip.xml` is part of this project. I am not sure where this file is requested and which component is complaining about not finding it. I could be wrong though about my assumption...

I like to know if this error message is related to `maven` or something else.

I'd appreciate your thought and advice on this.

[update]:

After adding `src/assembly/zip.xml` with following contents it fixed the problem however it builds two jar files under `target` directory.

```
FooProject-1.0.0-jar.jar
FooProject-1.0.0.jar
```

I am not sure why. I only want `FooProject-1.0.0.jar`.

[pom.xml]:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>yoon.pkg</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>foo.bar.pkg</groupId>
<artifactId>FooProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>FooProject</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<build>
    <finalName>FooProject-1.0.0</finalName>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>...</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

[Build Failure Msg]:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.482s
[INFO] Finished at: ....
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/1204M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly- 
plugin:2.4:single (create-zip) on project FooProject: 
Error reading assemblies: Error locating assembly descriptor: 
./src/assembly/zip.xml
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] [1] [INFO] Searching for file location: D:\somepath\FooProject\.\src\assembly\zip.xml
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] [2] [INFO] File: D:\somepath\FooProject\.\src\assembly\zip.xml does not 
exist.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] [3] [INFO] File: D:\somepath\FooProject\.\src\assembly\zip.xml does not 
exist.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463721/maven-assembly-error-reading-assemblies

Comment: can you please add mvn.xml to know further.

Comment: Could you share the `pom.xml` file? That file probably contains a configuration for `src\assembly\zip.xml` - and this file should be part of the Maven project. At any rate, that zip.xml file is needed to build the project

Comment: @Arun and @Daniele. I am about to add contents of `pom.xml`.

Comment: @Malt, I am consuming the article you shared with me. Ty for the link!

Comment: After creating src/assembly/zip.xml file with minimal content, the error msg went away, it built just fine.

Comment: just fyi `src/assembly/zip.xml` was found from parent mvn project folder.